Batch georeferencing of aerial imagery above the ocean using R
I am working with aerial imagery collected above open water. The raw images are not georeferenced. I am using the closest position recorded by the aircraft (based on timestamps) as the coordinate for the centre of the picture.
Is there a way to batch geo-reference the pictures (ideally in R), using the following information:

lat/lon position of the centre pixel
Image dimension (in pixels)
Spatial resolution or ground sampling distance (in cm per pixel)
Plateform yaw angle (i.e. orientation of the aircraft to North)

This is how I compute the extent of the pictures:
  Calculate_extent <- function(lat, lon, image_width, image_height, gsd) {

  
  Picture_centre <- st_sfc(st_point(c(lon, lat)), crs = 4326)
  
  Picture_centre_UTM <- st_transform(Picture_centre , crs = 32629)
  UTM_coords <- st_coordinates(Picture_centre_UTM )
  
  # Calculate extents in meters
  extent_width <- image_width * gsd / 100
  extent_height <- image_height * gsd / 100
  
  # Calculate corners based on the center point
  min_x <- utm_coords[1] - extent_width / 2
  max_x <- utm_coords[1] + extent_width / 2
  min_y <- utm_coords[2] - extent_height / 2
  max_y <- utm_coords[2] + extent_height / 2
  
  return(c(min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y))
}

How can I rotate the image / correct the corner coordinates based on the yaw angle of the aircraft ?
I tried using gdalUtilities or imager but when opening rasters in ArcGIS there is always something off. The images either aren't rotated properly or have uneven cell sizes and incorrect footprints. If I'm correct, the cell size should match the ground sampling distance in both dimensions and the footprint should be cell size * number of cells.

I think the problem is that rasters (in GDAL and hence raster terra packages) are always CRS axis-aligned, so you either have to create a rotated coordinate system that matches the heading of the aircraft or do a lossy rotation via trigonometry to a new axis system which might not be best done to the same cell size. If you could share a sample image with metadata, or if you can't share actual data a test image with test (but realistic) metadata that would help.
